# Parse script file (using Java)

Tags: java, parsing, recursion

The file contains

```
JAR_REPO=/ssnl/col/brf/jar
JAR_LOC=$JAR_REPO/log4.1.1j.jar
JAR_LOC=$JAR_LOC;$JAR_REPO/SnailClient.jar
FINAL_PATH=$JAR_REPO;$JAR_LOC;
```

The expected parsed string or value for FINAL_PATH will be like

```
/ssnl/col/brf/jar;/ssnl/col/brf/jar/log4.1.1j.jar;/ssnl/col/brf/jar/SnailClient.jar
```

How to achieve this using recursive call.
Thanks in advance

Wells

Comment: Note that `JAR_LOC` is defined twice—the second time, in terms of itself. This can cause problems with naive recursive evaluation (will fall into an infinite loop). I have sample code that works if you rename the first `JAR_LOC` into something else, like `LOG4J_JAR`.

Comment: Instead of 'Properties', we can use Map (prefer. 'LinkedHashMap' to maintain in same order). So during iteration when value contain $, getvalue from map. Still we need to parse the value based on ; and /. Does it meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

If the script file will only contain lines of the form

```
KEY=value
```

With *unique* keys, then you can load it using [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Then, all you need to do is check the value of the desired key if it contains any strings of the form `$WORD` and if `WORD` is also a key in the loaded properties. If so, then recursively evaluate the value for that key. This approach, however, will fall into an infinite loop if a variable is redefined in terms of itself.

---

Since your sample data includes variable re-assignment and recursion, then the solution is to evaluate each line of the file one at time, and storing the results of evaluation into a `Map`—a technique similar to memoization.

Here's the gist of the code:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([A-Z_0-9]+)");

    Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
    FileReader f = new FileReader("input");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(f);

    for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null;
        line = in.readLine()) {
        String[] parts = line.split("=", 2);
        String key = parts[0];

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(parts[1]);
        while (m.find()) {
            String var = m.group(1);
            m.appendReplacement(sb, vars.get(var));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);

        String value = sb.toString();
        vars.put(key, value);
        System.out.println(key + " <= " + value);
    }

    in.close();
    f.close();
}
```

Outputs

```
JAR_REPO <= /ssnl/col/brf/jar
JAR_LOC <= /ssnl/col/brf/jar/log4.1.1j.jar
JAR_LOC <= /ssnl/col/brf/jar/log4.1.1j.jar;/ssnl/col/brf/jar/SnailClient.jar
FINAL_PATH <= /ssnl/col/brf/jar;/ssnl/col/brf/jar/log4.1.1j.jar;/ssnl/col/brf/jar/SnailClient.jar;
```

As expected.